# What's wrong with the jQuery live method?

Tags: jquery

The [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method was deprecated in jQuery 1.7. The jQuery docs now recommend

> Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

I understand how `on` and `delegate` work, but I don't understand why they are better. `live()` is simpler and easier to use.

Is there a reason why `live` was deprecated? How are the other methods better? Will anything bad happen if I continue to use `live`?

Comment: Other than your code breaking when they stop supporting it?  Not much... especially if you use a local copy of jQuery...

Comment: The answers below are good, but there's one practical aspect to deprecation: the toolkit developers no longer need to support `live`. Since they've added `on` and think that it's a good solution, they no longer want to have to support and maintain `live`, so they have deprecated it, regardless of whether it is bad or good. In this case, there are some reasons to avoid `live`, but in the general case, if a method is added to a toolkit for *any* reason, the developers may choose to deprecate methods that perform similar actions for ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See some of the explanations here:

> <strike>http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/why-jquery-live-is-a-bad-option-to-use/</strike> (Site appears to be down)

**Quote:**

1. You can’t use `.live()` for reusable widgets.
2. `.stopPropagation()` doesn’t work with live.
3. `.live()` is slower.
4. `.live()` is not chainable.

**Further** beauty of `.on()` is that it streamlines all events quite well: http://api.jquery.com/on/

D'uh you know about the api link and see how `.on()` works :)

**Quote:**

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For
>   help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(),
>   .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see
>   .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes
>   itself, see .one()

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that `.live()` was removed in jQuery 1.9, points 1, 2 and 3 need to be heavily qualified, and point 4 is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 10):

`live()` is inefficient for two reasons:

- In the construct `$('selector').live()`, jQuery first has to select all elements. However, when calling `live()`, it only needs the selector of the jQuery object (stored in `.selector`) and doesn't actually use any of the selected elements. Therefore, it is somewhat wasteful to first select all matching elements and then not using them. `on()` and `delegate()` take the target selector as a *parameter* which means that no target elements are selected beforehand and the testing occurs only when the event is triggered.
- `live()` by default is bound at the `document` level, thus all events need to bubble up through the whole DOM. You *can* narrow it down by specifying a context with `$(selector, context).live()`, but it's better to use `on()` or `delegate()` for this.

When writing new code, it is strongly recommended to use the latest and greatest `on()` instead of `delegate()` and the deprecated `live()`. However, I don't think support for `live()` will be dropped anytime soon (if ever), as so many scripts rely on it. Also, there's no real disadvantage of using `live()` over `on()`, as in the jQuery source itself `live()` is defined as:

```
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
}
```

Comment: `$(selector, context)` doesn't change `.context`, so it would still be `document`. You have to pass dom element like `$($("body")[0]).find("span")` to change `.context` to something else

Answer (score 4):

There are two main issues with the `live` method:

1. It attaches all event handlers at the document level, so any event that bubbles up to the document has to be matched against the event types and selectors for all live events. If you have a lot of events, the page will be sluggish. You should use `delegate` or `on` to limit the scope of where you check the events.
2. The usage of the method is not typical for how selectors is used with other methods in the library. You can only use it on jQuery objects that are created using a selector. The `delegate` and `on` methods makes this natural as you supply the selector to the method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm rather sure this is due to the nature of `.live()`. It's convinient and all, but it's a bad practice to use since it forces your browser to in most cases search for more events then required.

Instead of by default searching the entire documents for a certain event, it's more data efficient to search a specific container.

`live()` indeed was convenient to use, and most os uf never noticed any flaws with using it. It was basicly an improved `bind()` in my eyes.

But in many times we have to adapt and be more clear to our code on what needs to be executed.

It's like asking yourself why you have to import stuff, and why not everything is imported at the initiation.

Comment: I thought you could limit the search by the selection string, i.e. `"#mydiv .edit"` rather than `".edit"`.

Comment: Not really. live() will always check if there's a `.edit` inside a `#mydiv` in the entire document on every event execution. Not find an existing `#mydiv` and check its children.

Answer (score 1):

`live()` attaches the handlers to the document, which basically results in intercepting *all* events of the given kind, incurring the cost for a search for elements matching the selector. with `delegate()` and `on()`, you are recommended to attach closer to the expected targets (in their direct parent, if possible), thus narrowing the number of handled events, and respectively searches for matching targets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a detailed [article by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2010/on-jquery-live/) about live() performance and limits.

If you continue using `live`, soon or later your code could not work anymore if you upgrade the jQuery library on your projects.

Answer (score 0):

`$('some selector').live(' ... ', handler)`

is the same as

`$(document).on(' ... ', 'some selector', handler)`

So when you use `live` you actually assign all your handlers to the root of your DOM tree. There are two disadvantages for that:

1. Attaching handlers to DOM root increases the path the event has to traverse while buubling up. That would impact performance in a bad way.
2. There's an increased risk that some other handler with `return false` at the end will prevent `live` handler from firing.