# live click showing another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, show

I have two div's that are being placed in the DOM after the page loads, with jquery. I'm having a hard time binding one div action to showing another element. Any pointers?

```
  jQuery('#create-account-btn').live('click',function(){
    jQuery('#create-account').show();
    jQuery(this).hide();
  });
```

Create-account will now show

Comment: Just so you know, `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.+.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more clearly what is going wrong with the code you've shown? You said "Create-account will now show", so what's the problem?

Comment: Your code works just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbj/Kk6MR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Zvd8J/

Jquery `.on` event read more here but only above v 1.7 : http://api.jquery.com/on/ `.live` here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

if you keen: [What's the difference between jQuery .live() and .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042576/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-on)

Further if you become more keen: see here why : [What's wrong with the jQuery live method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926)

Took liberty to jot down small html and demo for you.

Hope this helps, `:)`

Also note: you could do this:

```
$(document).on('click','#create-account-btn',function(){

});
```

**code**

```
$('.hulk').hide();
$('#create-account-btn').on('click',function(){
    $('.hulk').hide();
    $('#create-account').show();

  });

$('#foo').on('click',function(){
    $('.hulk').hide();
    $('#create-whatever').show();

  });
```

**html**

```
<div class="hulk" id="create-whatever">
hulk yada yada
</div>
  <div class="hulk" id="create-account">
ironman yada yada crea accoutn show
</div>
<input type="button" id="create-account-btn" value="click me" />

<input type="button" id="foo" value="click me to show another" />
```

Comment: If replacing `.live()` with `.on()` that's not the syntax you use (for elements loaded after dom ready). See http://api.jquery.com/live for how to port to `.on()`.

Comment: Hiya @nbrooks Howz it going man! `:)` cheers, I have also updated few helpful stuff for OP.