# jquery event could not be bound

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
show('<div class="alignLeft"><div id="ownerinfo"></div><br /><h3>Where will the document go?</h3><select id="dest"><option value="">-- select destination --</option><option>'+this.DESTINATIONS.join('</option><option>')+'</option></select><h3>Notes</h3><input type="text" id="notes" size="70" /><p><button id="regbtn">Register</button></p></div>','append',function(){
            $('#regbtn').click(function(){
                alert('ok');
            });
            alert($('#regbtn').click);
        });
```

The above is the code. `show()` is just a function that adds animation but executes third parameter after animation. It works with other functions. However, the problem is in `$('#regbtn').click()` -> I cannot seem to bind it. What could be the problem here?

I'm hoping that even if I don't upload the whole code you can help me figure it out. When i alert the `.click`, this is the output:

```
function (a,c){c==null&&(c=a,a=null);return arguments.length>0?this.bind(b,a,c):this.trigger(b)}
```

Comment: try using: `$('#regbtn').on("click" , function(){});` instead. Works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be appending the element dynamically, so please try `.on` even to ping click event:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Please lemme know if I missed anything!

**script**

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

**code**

```
$('#regbtn').on('click',function(){
                alert('ok');
            });
```

or

```
   $(document).on('click','#regbtn',function(){
                    alert('ok');
                });
```

Comment: `.click(fn)` is a shorthand for `.on('click', fn)` in jQuery 1.7+ (no event delegation if there's no context selector). Your updated 2nd code may work if it's an event delegation issue though.

Comment: It now says: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: Most likely because you're using jQuery < 1.7

Comment: @FabrícioMatté indeed `:)` re:OP please read the above comment and if you are keen further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926

Comment: @rationalboss add this on top of your page: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>` and you will unleash the awesomeness! `:)`

Comment: Okay, I was using 1.6.4. I'm now using the latest 1.8.0. Can anyone help me understand why .click() wasn't working and the .on() suddenly worked? Thanks! :)

Comment: @rationalboss lol all good, Glad it helped! `:)` you were adding the element dynamically to the DOM on load dont know about your new element where as when you used `.on` api further read here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ delegation and beyond et. al.

Comment: You can only bind handlers to elements currently present in the DOM, when the elements are removed their handlers also go away. With Tats' 2nd method, you're actually binding a handler to the `document` which is always there. There's a dozen of event delegation questions/day, maybe Tats has a nice link explaining it simply `=]` The [api page](http://api.jquery.com/on/) also has some throughout explanations.

Comment: i see. since the #regbtn will actually be removed too when the user navigates, will it hurt if it is a .on on the $(document)? :)

Comment: go the @FabrícioMatté `:))`! re:OP the api link will makes it more clear, `:)`

Comment: OP, yeah, if the element is removed and then re-appended, you'll have to either A. Re-attach the handler or B. Attach it to `document` (or a closer static ancestor element) with `.on` (this is usually the cleanest way).

Comment: Okay, thanks! the API page is long. I'm using that .on as a "hack" to make that part of my code work. :)