# div slide open then close

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a two box, with the first box having an ***"Open"*** `<button>`

```
<div id="box1">
    <button id="open" type="button">Open</button>
</div>
<div id="box2"></div>​
```

When clicking the ***"Open"*** `<button>` the first box will slide to the left by 50%, then change the ***"Open"*** to ***"Close"*** button. I came up with this jQuery solution:

```
$(function() {
    $('#open').on('click', function() {
        $('#box1').animate({
            right: '50%'
        }, 500, function() {
            $('#open').text('Close').attr('id', 'close');
        });
    });

    $('#close').on('click', function() {
        $('#box1').animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500, function() {
            // alert('done');
        });
    });
});​
```

I managed to change the `ID` and text of the `<button>` (checked via Inspect Element). However when I click the ***"Close"*** `<button>` it is not working. What seems to be the problem in here? I even tried `alert(1)` on the `$('#close')` to see if it does see the ***Close*** `ID` but no luck.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QLpVM/1/).

Comment: My account seems to be intimidating to answer because of poor reputation. However, I do marked an answer if I find it fit and answered my question.

Comment: Bruv, everyone here are there to help you, nothing to do with reputation, I have **+1-ed** you, rest see my post below, hope I can help you `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fFEuT/)

Another demo thanks @Sheikh: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TXyUM/)

Hope it fits your cause `:)`

**code**

```
   $(function() {
    $('#open').on('click', function() {
        $('#box1').animate({
            right: '50%'
        }, 500, function() {
            $('#open').text('Close').attr('id', 'close');
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#close', function() {
        $('#box1').animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500, function() {
            alert('done');
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks Bruver @SheikhHeera `:)` for Edit!

Comment: Thanks and Check your `demo` again and try to click on the `close` button several times.

Comment: Cheerios @SheikhHeera `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/TXyUM/ +1'd you and further it shall be remembered `:)` added `$(document).on('click', '#close', function() {...});`

Comment: Although this seems to solve my problem, there is some kind of delay after clicking close before the closing animation.

Answer (score 3):

If you change your

```
$('#close').on('click', function(){...});
```

to this

```
$('#box1').on('click', '#close', function(){...});
```

then this will work like [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QLpVM/15/) but also you can make it working in other ways like [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QLpVM/30/).

Comment: Thanks for this, however I have hard time yet looking at those functions/classes. I prefer the simple way, for now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Also make close animation `right: '20%'`

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bondye/QLpVM/9/)

Comment: Its lil incorrect, Just an advise, `.live` is deprected from Jquery - *If Keen read this* - `:)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926 *also* look into delegate, but I reckon main issue for OP is something else `:)` I thought I will mention it as an FYI only bruv.

Answer (score 1):

try using `toggle` without changing it's id  **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/QLpVM/10/)**

```
$('#open').toggle(function() {
    $('#box1').animate({
        right: '50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $('#open').text('Close');
    });
}, function(){
    $('#box1').animate({
        right: '20%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $('#open').text('Open');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this on Google when searching for a popup bottom sliding box.

I've adapted the above code and created a bottom slider that brings up an iframe, perfect if you want to display a quick survey about the page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/redwall/r5FBm/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="box1">
<button id="open" type="button">Open</button>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="100%" height="170" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

JAVA:

```
$(function () {
$('#open').on('click', function () {
    $('#box1').animate({
        height: '230px'
    }, 500, function () {
        $('#open').text('Close').attr('id', 'close');
    });
});

$('#box1').on('click', '#close', function () {
    $('#box1').animate({
        height: '50px'
    }, 500, function () {
        $('#close').text('Open').attr('id', 'open');
    });
});
```

});

CSS:

```
    #box1 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background:#FF800D;
    overflow:hidden;
}
button {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```