# What are the reasons that live() and bind() are deprecated post jQuery 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

As of post jQuery 1.7 the `.live()` and `.bind()` are deprecated and instead of that `.on()`
is being used. Both of these were great functions were working like charm. What is purpose of removal? What is the technical reason behind that?

And why `.on()` is proffered to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with the jQuery live method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method)

Comment: I'm saying this quite a lot lately, but `bind()` is *not* deprecated, and neither are `unbind()`, `delegate()` and `undelegate()`. It is recommended to use `on()` and `off()` instead, but you can still use the "older" methods if you want to support jQuery releases prior to 1.7. Only `live()` and `die()` were deprecated, then removed in 1.9.

Comment: @MohammadAdil, i know how to use `.on()` instead of `.live()`. Perhaps you have not clearly got my question.

Comment: The linked question does answer you question IMO: *"Further beauty of .on() is that it streamlines all events"* That's the reason why it is preferred. All event handling is unified.

Comment: You need look no further than jQuery's own [`.live()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for an explanation as to why it was deprecated. (The jQuery doco is a good first stop for any jQuery questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from this [article](http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/why-jquery-live-is-a-bad-option-to-use/):

1. You can’t use live for reusable widgets.
2. stopPropagate() doesn’t work in live
3. Live is slower
4. Live isn’t chainable