# Set height to element dynamically and change height on window resizes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project where I need to set the height dynamically, means when the page loads the height must be set to itself and it's a responsive box, so when the browser window resizes the height increases but I am unable to fix it. I shared the script below. It's not something to calculate with window height or else, it should set and change the height based on window resizes. Any help?

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

```js
var itemHeight = $('.item').height();
$('.item').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    height: itemHeight + 'px'
  });
});

$(window).on('resize', function(event) {

  $('.item').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      height: itemHeight + 'px'
    });
  });
});
```

Please see the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rj1xy1ue/

Comment: You have to put your itemHeight in the resize event.

Comment: Ok, I put itemHeight to resize event but no changes in result

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to use `%` instead of `px`. px will fix the value, but % will automatically compute the values based on the available viewport.

```
var itemHeight = 20; //Sample value
$('.item').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        height: itemHeight + '%'
    });
});
```

Simply, find the perfect value of `itemHeight` which is ideal for your case and then assign it. No need for extra `resize` event handler.

**In your current code, in resize event you are assigning same value again which doesn't make any difference to the dimension. Hence you are not able to see the difference on resize.**

Try this:

```
var itemHeight = $('.item').height();

function resizer() {
    $('.item').each(function () {
        $(this).css({
            height: itemHeight + 'px'
        });
    });
}
$(window).on('resize', function (event) {
    itemHeight = 350 //any different value
    resizer();
});
```

Sample Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/822/

**Note:** Make sure you change the value of `itemHeight` in resize handler

Comment: I am not looking for percentage solution, like I said it's not something that I am looking which will calculate with viewport/window size. Percentage solution won't work unless I give a fixed height to parent item.

Comment: I just want to give the <div class="item"></div> a height onload, and change the height when window resizes based on the content

Comment: Unless using an old version of jQuery (< 1.6), you should use `.on()` in place of `.bind()`. Otherwise, good answer and a +1

Comment: Doesn't change anything on-resize

Comment: You have to change the value of itemHeight. Otherwise it will assign same old value. This no change

Comment: @gibberish I checked with .on() but not any change in result. I am using jquery-1.11.2.min.js and jquery-migrate.min.js (latest version)

Comment: @KK From your code If I keep the "itemHeight = 350 " on resizer event() then div.item gets 350px height but on window resize it doesn't change,

Comment: @Kcoitk That's what I mentioned, you have to compute the itemHeight value inside resize handler.

Comment: @Kcoitk You will not see any difference, but `.bind()` has been deprecated and will vanish from some future version of jQuery. Also [see the description here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924175/what-are-the-reasons-that-live-and-bind-are-deprecated-post-jquery-1-7)

Comment: @KK itemHeight value is dynamic

Comment: @KK can you share a fiddle without any window.height() or any parent item calculation? I am also able to run my it with window.height() or parent items but not itself.

Comment: The link which I shared has this stuff. IF you want to test it,just resize the editor to see the calculations

Comment: but please I don't want any calcualtion to parent or window.height(). it should change it's height on resize based on it's(div class="item"></div>) height itself

Comment: Just use `height: auto;` in your window resize event.

Comment: You are not understanding it. The point I am trying to make here is that your code is fine. The only problem is that the itemHeight value doesn't change at all and hence on every resize, all the item divs are assigned a common fixed value. Since the value doesn't change, it appears to you that the code is not working.The code works fine. Try computing the value of itemHeight before assigning it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called Responsive design.

A key idea in responsive design is to use percentages in place of px.

See these references:

[WebDesignerWall on Responsive Design](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design)

[CSS-Tricks question](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/responsive-web-design-when-to-use-px-vs-on-margins-and-padding/)

for some ideas.

Note that using percentages for height is not as important as for width. You might also want to check out

[Responsive Layouts with flexbox](http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/responsive-layouts-with-flexbox/)

---

On the jQuery side, you can use something like this:

```
var win = $(window);

$(function() {

    win_size_recalc();

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        win_size_recalc();
    });

}); //end document.ready

function win_size_recalc(){
    ww = win.width();

    //EXAMPLE OF USE:
    if (ww <= 550){
        $('#header').css({'height':'50px'});
        $('nav').css({'height':'55px'});
        $('#headerstuff').css({'width':'98%'});
    }else if (ww <= 650){
        $('#headerstuff').css({'width':'98%'});
        $('nav').css({'width':'98%'});
    }else if (ww <= 770){
        $('#headerstuff').css({'width':'90%'});
        $('nav').css({'width':'90%'});
    }else if (ww <= 850){
        $('#headerstuff').css({'width':'90%'});
        $('nav').css({'width':'90%'});
    }else if (ww <= 900){
        //etc etc
}
```

---

You might also want to check out CSS media queries, which is the CSS way of doing what we just did above using jQuery:

https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

[and more](https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=%40media)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the main problem is you're only calculating `itemHeight` once. This fiddle shows a more modern way to use jQuery to achieve your goals (use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)):

http://jsfiddle.net/sean9999/7j4sz3wv/6/

```js
$(function(){
    "use strict";
    var resizeBoxes = function(){
        var padding = 25;
        var parentHeight = $('body').height() - padding;
        $('#debug').html( 'parent height = ' + parentHeight );
        $('.item').css('height',parentHeight);
    };
    $(window).on('resize',resizeBoxes);
    resizeBoxes();
});
```

```css
body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FED;
}
#debug {
    width: 50%;    
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: navy;
}
.item {
    min-width: 25px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    background-color: silver;
    min-height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share a code without window.height() calculation, Like I said nothing to calculate with window/viewport height

Comment: sure, so long as you have a containing div you can query for that information. I've updated the code to offer a solution free of window / viewport height

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am able to understand your question correctly but I'll give a try based on what I could understand anyway.

You want the `.item` objects to resize on `resize` event of `window` object such that you want to start with whatever `.height()` these `.item` objects have, and then scale proportionally to the `window` height on `resize`.

If this is what you wanted, the solution is pretty simple. You calculate the difference in `.height()` of `window` object, and you add (or remove) that difference to the default `.height()` of `.item` objects.

Take a look at **[this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jodrxj4h/)** and resize the height of the result panel to observe the difference in height of the `.item` objects. And tell me if this is what you were expecting the result to be.

The JavaScript used in the example is as below:

```
var items = $('.item');
var windowObject = $(window);
var defaultWinHeight = windowObject.height();
var defaultItemHeight = items.height();
items.css({ height: defaultItemHeight + 'px' });
windowObject.on('resize', function (event) {
    var currWinHeight = windowObject.height();
    var difference = currWinHeight - defaultWinHeight;
    var itemHeight = defaultItemHeight + difference;
    items.css({ height: itemHeight + 'px' });
});
```

Apologies if this is not what you were looking for. Hope it helps in some way though.

***Update #1:***

And here is another **[resulting jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4k4semk/)** of the same experiment but involving calculating percentages.

JavaScript:

```
var items = $('.item');
var windowObject = $(window);
var defaultWinHeight = windowObject.height();
var defaultItemHeight = items.height();
items.css({ height: defaultItemHeight + 'px' });
windowObject.on('resize', function (event) {
    var currWinHeight = windowObject.height();
    var currWinPercent = (currWinHeight/defaultWinHeight)*100;
    var itemHeight = (currWinPercent/100)*defaultItemHeight;
    items.css({ height: itemHeight + 'px' });
});
```