# How to redirect response from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to redirect to a page from response. I made a ajax call and can handle success. There is html page in response, but how to redirect it to that page.
Here's my code.

```
$("#launchId").live('click',function(){
    var id= $("#id").val();
    var data = 'id='+id;
    $.ajax({
        url: "xyz.json",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        complete : function(response) {
             window.location.href = response;                  
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: live is deprecated !!!

Comment: @hemanth is response a url?

Comment: Add a `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` before `window.location.href = response;` and post what you get here.

Comment: Is this used for a mobile HTML website?

Comment: no response is a object that has total html content

Comment: @zer02 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!DOCTYPE html...." status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: can u show the object structure

Comment: You are not using 'success' callback here but 'complete'. What if your server returns an error? I'll suggest you to use 'success' callback instead.

Comment: @hemanth: Why do you use ajax for that? Just let a form submit to that URL and load the page as one normally would do. Btw, giving a html file a `.json` extension is odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using ajax would make this easier:

```
<form type="POST" action="xyz.json">
    <label for="id">Enter ID:</label><input id="id" name="id">
    <button type="submit" id="launchId">Send</button>
</form>
```

If you really want to use ajax, you should generate a distinct server response, containing only the HTML parts you want to update in your page or actual JSON.

If you insist on using the response which you currently get, the appropriate way of dealing with it would be [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "xyz.json",
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html', // it's no JSON response!
    success: function(response) {
         document.write(response); // overwrite current document
    },
    error: function(err) {
         alert(err+" did happen, please retry");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this.

```
var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
newDoc.write(response.responseText);
newDoc.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response is an object containing the full HTML for a page in the `responseText` property.

You can probably do `$(body).html(response.responseText);` instead of `window.location.href = ...;` to overwrite the current page content with what you got a response.

```
...
complete : function(response) {
    $(body).html(response.responseText);
}
```

But i suggest you don't and there could be style and other conflicts with whats already there on the page.

Comment: And if the complete page is getting updated it would be better if he just submits a form right?

Comment: @TusharMathur - Yes, no real need for AJAX post in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML add a div with id as 'content', something like this

```
<div id='content'/>
```

Since your response is html in your complete function append the content into the div like this -

```
 complete : function(response) {
         $('#content').append(response.responseText);
    }
```

Let me know if you still face issues.

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
$("#launchId").live('click',function(){
    var id= $("#id").val();
    var data = 'id='+id;
    $.ajax({
        url: "xyz.json",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        complete : function(response) {
             window.location.href = '/yourlocation?'+response;                  
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: plz explain what is "live method is deprecated" ? @Baadshah

Comment: @SubhraSekharMukhopadhyay see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method

Comment: kk thanx for downVoting @Bergi

Comment: @Subhra: It wasn't me, so I cannot remove the downvote. And the answer is still invalid, as the op claims `response` to be HTML markup instead of an URI part.