# How to redirect to seperate View from ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So my question is similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871289/how-to-redirect-response-from-ajax-request)  but I can not simply overwrite the document.

I'm using **MVC** and am able to call a controller's entry point from a `View` other than it's own.

the View (Say, *ViewA*) has a dialog, defined as:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 390,
            width: 402,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '/Result/Result', 
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            window.location.href = "<%:Url.Action("~/Result/Result")%>";
                        }
                    });

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                cancel: function(){ $(this).close();}}
           });
```

When I confirm the dialog, I hit the entry point I wanted to in the `ResultsController`, but then my browser navigates to *localhost:8000/ViewA/~/Result/Result* instead of *localhost:8000/Result/Result*

**ResultController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Result()
{            
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

How can I redirect to the page returned by `Result()` in the different controller?

Comment: whyy can't you just use the string `"/Result/Result"` ? Or return the proper url in response?

Comment: Try changing your `Url.Action` to read `Url.Action("Result", "Result")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Url.Action("~/Result/Result")
```

To

```
Url.Action("Result", "Result")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758(v=vs.118).aspx