# jquery .on() from append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really confuse about how to add a click event to element created by jquery.

Now, I generate elements like this:

```
$.ajax(
    params....
)
.done(function(item){
    $.each(item, function(i, some){
        a = '<p>some text</p>';
        $(node).before(a);
    }
});
```

my problem is when I try to add a click event to element "p". If I do:

```
$('p').on('click', 'p', function(){
    alert('yai!');
});
```

Is showing nothing. BUt if I do:

```
$.ajax(
    params....
)
.done(function(item){
    $.each(item, function(i, some){
        a = '<p>some text</p>';
        $(a).click(function(){
            alert('yai!');
        });
        $(node).before(a);
    }
});
```

It show too many alerts (the same number of p elements)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the second case you should not see any alert actually. The element you bind the handler to is never added to the DOM (you are parsing the HTML string twice, once with `$(a)` and once with `.beofre(a)`, thus creating two different DOM elements). But maybe you simplified the code too much. I recommend to read the documentation to learn about event handlers: http://learn.jquery.com/events/.

Comment: Replace `$('p')` with `$(document)`

Comment: Assign a class for those `p`'s in order to handle them easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options:

1. **(recommended)** You could bind that `click` event `on` on the parent element. This is the best method because irrespective of the number of `p` inside its the parent the `click` is always attached to the parent and that makes it DRY and more performant.

   ```
   $("YourParentElement").on('click', 'p', function(){
      alert('yai!');
   });
   ```
2. You could place your event handler with `$("p")` as selector *after* the `$.each` loop. At that time your `p` elements would be in DOM and so you can bind the click handler to the element. (*Disadvantage* : You'd be attaching the click handler to every single `p`, which is sometimes an overhead if you have a large number of similar `p`s)

   ```
   $.ajax(
     params....
   ).done(function(item){
      $.each(item, function(i, some){
          a = '<p>some text</p>';   
          // Click() was here causing it ////////
          //  to loop multiple times           //
          $(node).before(a);                   //
      }); ///////////////////////////////////////
          //
        / / / moved here
       $("p").click(function(){
           alert('yai!');
       });
    });
   ```
3. You could bind this element (`p`) to the `document` object which always exists, even before jquery is loaded. And its not there now in the API. Going in those lines, it definitely not better to use `live`. For info on why `live` is evil, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats).

Comment: The main reason against `live` is that it did unneccessary selection, not that it bound to the document

Comment: noted :) in my defense i didnt speak abt the reasons why `live` was evil, i just pointed OP to the link :)

Comment: OK, maybe will this work, but what happens if the parent element is generated by jquery too?

Comment: There will be a parent element at some point which is static. It neednt be immediate. Just a parent

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try below code to bind click event to paragraph tag.

```
$("p").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Hope this will help you.