# How to Append and Remove Column Divs

Tags: jquery

I've trying to solve this for a while, I would appreciate any help. 
I have three columns. Each of the columns contains a pair of Add/Remove buttons at the top. I would like for the add button to append a clone of the parent column after the parent.I've tried various methods for cloning the parent div but to no avail.

I would also like for the remove button to remove the containing column. I only managed to have first column work with the remove button. This function does not work with the following Columns.

I would be very appreciative for some assistance. Thanks you.

http://jsfiddle.net/equiroga/h2dnn/2/

```
   $(document).ready( function() {

    $("#add").click( function() {
    $(".day-column").append(".day-column");
    $('.day-column').clone().attr('class','.day-column').insertAfter('.day-      column:first');
    });

    $("#remove").click( function() {
     $(".day-column:first").remove('.day-column:first');
     });

     });
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle has some curious HTML: `<article idhttp://jsfiddle.net/#save="timeline-container">`. Typo?

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/2WUtB/

EDIT 2: **Demo 2** http://jsfiddle.net/RNW24/ with the use of `$(this).closest('section.day-column').clone()` you will only clone the nearest section not the whole lot which was happening in your case! `:)` Jquery has good documentation I reckon play around and you will be a happy lad! http://api.jquery.com/closest/

To add click with dynamically generated element you need to use `.on` API.

API: `.on` : http://api.jquery.com/on/

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For
>   help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), 
>   .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see
>   .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes
>   itself, see .one()

2ndly, remove "id=add" as you are duplicating the `id` and identity is always unique, use `class` instead.

3rdly html is bit wonky I will leave that on your project lead to get UI guys to decide.

Hope this helps `:)`

some helpful links:

- [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)
- [What's wrong with the jQuery live method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926)

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
        alert('Click is bind with add button');
        $("ul").append("<li></li>");
        $('.day-column').clone().attr('class', '.day-column').insertAfter('.day-column:first');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        alert('Click is bind with remove button');
        $(".day-column:first").remove('.day-column:first');

    });

});
```

Comment: @ Tats_innit thanks. The method worked but unfortunately, it also cloned the entire row of columns after the first column. I just want the first column (parent) to clone a duplicate column after itself. I certainly appreciate your effort. Thanks for the insights. Cheers.

Comment: @LeroyTah-dowHerschelSilverm Glad it helped `:))` saweet dude, I will take a look when I am free!

Comment: @ Tats_innit I didn't mean any disrespect. I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm still figuring my stuff out. I asked for too much. I appreciate you sharing your knowledge and solutions. I'll be careful not to make the same mistake in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @LeroyTah-dowHerschelSilverm LOl all cool bruv `:)` I will read the whole code and get back to you! Take easy yo!

Comment: @ Tats_innit, Dude, Thank you! If your ever in chicago, look me up. I'll buy you a beer.

Comment: @LeroyTah-dowHerschelSilverm Done! I will! Now never RageQuite SO `:)` gimme me couple of hours I will look into this issue eh!

Comment: @LeroyTah-dowHerschelSilverm Here you go, now if you will click in the `add list` for section 1 it will only `clone` section 1 **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/RNW24/ I will update the answer and have a good one! `:)` and if this help dont forget to accept the post!