# Changing title of each accordion

Tags: jquery

I'm using accordion jQuery UI , in each accordion there are some fields, 
I want to be able to change each accordion Title by using the first input[type=text] of each accordion

This JS which I wrote, but only work for the first input[type=text] of the first accordion
and I want for each accordion

```
$('.redux-groups-accordion-group input[type=text]:first').live('keyup',function(event) {
     $(this).parents('.redux-groups-accordion-group:first').find('.redux-groups-header').text(event.target.value);
});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="redux-groups-accordion">
    <div class="redux-groups-accordion-group">
        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header">
            <span class="redux-groups-header">New Slide Title</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="ui-accordion-content">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" />
            <input type="text" name="title" />
            <input type="text" name="tags" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="redux-groups-accordion-group">
        <h3 class="ui-accordion-header">
            <span class="redux-groups-header">New Slide Title</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="ui-accordion-content">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" />
            <input type="text" name="title" />
            <input type="text" name="tags" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/v7XgA/

by the way `live` is deprecated:

- Old post: [What's wrong with the jQuery live method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926)

I have use `.on` instead of `live` also you were using `:first` in your Jq code hence it was aiming for all get rid of `:first`

Rest should fit the need `:)`

**Try this**

```
$('.redux-groups-accordion-group input[type=text]').on('keyup',function(event) {
     $(this).parents('.redux-groups-accordion-group:first').find('.redux-groups-header').text(event.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#redux-groups-accordion').on('keyup', '.redux-groups-accordion-group input[name="title"]', function (event) {
    $(this).closest('.redux-groups-accordion-group').find('.redux-groups-header').text(this.value);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E9dac/)