# Submit closest form with multiple select forms

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, closest

I have multiple forms on one page with a different name but in every form i use the same input name.

Now i want to submit the form when you change the select, this works but only for the first form.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#number_tickets").live("change keyup", function () {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
    });


<form name="form-1" id="form-1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="order/submit/1/" method="post" class="form_count">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row2['id']).'">
 <select name="number_tickets" id="number_tickets">
  <option selected disabled>Choose..</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </form>

<form name="form-2" id="form-2" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="order/submit/2/" method="post" class="form_count">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row2['id']).'">
 <select name="number_tickets" id="number_tickets">
  <option selected disabled>Choose..</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </form>

<form name="form-3" id="form-3" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="order/submit/3/" method="post" class="form_count">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row2['id']).'">
 <select name="number_tickets" id="number_tickets">
  <option selected disabled>Choose..</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </form>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id's of html elements should be unique. `.live()` was already considered an inefficient way to handle event binding, Because of that for future use you have to use `.on()`. Try:

```
$(function () {
        $("select[name='number_tickets']").on("change keyup", function () {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
    });
```

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm

[What's wrong with the jQuery live method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't have multiple HTML elements with the same `ID`, apart from that, you should change the selector using the field `NAME` instead. 
You should try to change the ID's of the `SELECT` fields.

```
$(function () {
        $("*[name='number_tickets']").live("change keyup", function () {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        });
    });


<form name="form-1" id="form-1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="order/submit/1/" method="post" class="form_count">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row2['id']).'">
 <select name="number_tickets" id="number_tickets1">
  <option selected disabled>Choose..</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </form>

<form name="form-2" id="form-2" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="order/submit/2/" method="post" class="form_count">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row2['id']).'">
 <select name="number_tickets" id="number_tickets2">
  <option selected disabled>Choose..</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </form>

<form name="form-3" id="form-3" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="order/submit/3/" method="post" class="form_count">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row2['id']).'">
 <select name="number_tickets" id="number_tickets3">
  <option selected disabled>Choose..</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID selectors such as "#number_tickets" only match the first element, use a class or html element to match all:

```
$(function () {
    $("select").live("change keyup", function () {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

EDIT: Also you seem to have forgotten to close the select tags , otherwise the above code will always submit the first form.