# Hide parent div on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

So I'm trying to write a super simple script that will allow a user to throw any link or button with the class `.close` inside of a div, and when that `.close` link is clicked, it automatically closes the parent container.

Here is what I'm currently trying to work with: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xyn4/)**

The code that I am currently trying to use is:

**HTML**

```
<div class="well notice bg-green">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <p>This is a notice that is green.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.well {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
.notice {
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 0px 15px;
}
.well.bg-green {
    background: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    color: #468847;
}
.close {
    color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    float: right;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 15px;
    opacity: .2;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
button.close {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$('.close').live("click", function () {
    $(this).parents('div').fadeOut;
});
```

Let me know if my question doesn't make sense or if any more elaboration is needed. Thank you!

Comment: `fadeOut` should be `fadeOut()`

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two problems:

- `live()` doesn't exist in the version of jQuery in your fiddle (deprecated in 1.7, removed in 1.9)
- `fadeOut` is a function (you were missing parens to execute it)

http://jsfiddle.net/KF7S6/

```
$('.close').on("click", function () {
    $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
});
```

If you want it to work on dynamic elements, use this version:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
    $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, that shows my true lack of experience with JavaScript but thank you so much for your help. Your code worked perfectly. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/6Xyn4/4/

```
$('.close').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

Recommended to use `.click()` now in place of deprecated `.live()`

Answer (score 3):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gL9rw/

Issue was `.live` which is deprecated now.

If you keen: [What's wrong with the jQuery live method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926) `:)`

**code**

```
$('.close').on("click", function () {
    $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link! I didn't know `.live` was deprecated, I was trying to piece together my code from other Stack Overflow questions (as I'm sure everyone noticed) haha.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should be `fadeOut()` not `fadeOut`

```
$('.close').click(function () {
  $(this).parents('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.live() is dead. use .on() delegates. Also you missed something, check below

```
$('body').on("click", '.close', function () {
        $(this).parents().fadeOut();
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xyn4/12/)